# Capture windows forms events(c#) hosted on mfc dialog

Tags: c#, clr, winforms-interop

How to get the window form events that is hosted on a MFC dialog?

I have a user control which is hosted on a MFC dialog. I have a button in that user control. I want to handle the click event of that button in the mfc dialog.

Hence I tried implementing it as specified in the MSDN.

[How to: Sink Windows Forms Events from Native C++ Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/af8w7d7d.aspx)

The steps described in MSDN is strictly followed in a project that supports CLR.
It compiles and runs well.
But events are not received by the mfc that has c# control hosted on it.

My questions are

1. Is there anything else to check upon to get the event sink?
2. What would happen if the event is handled in Managed side, will the control be back to host application?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem hence answering my own question.

1. Is there anything else to check upon to get the event sink?

   Going as per MSDN is right. What went wrong here is the attaching the Click event wrongly.

> i.e)
>   m_MyControl.GetControl()->button1->Click += MAKE_DELEGATE(
>   System::EventHandler, OnClick );
>
> My subscription was to control itself.
>
> m_MyControl.GetControl()->Click += MAKE_DELEGATE(
>   System::EventHandler, OnClick );

1. What would happen if the event is handled in Managed side, will the control be back to host application?

> ie. If click event is handled in both managed and host side.
>
> Well,first managed side receives the event, after that, host side receives it.